# Get a Object property from array of objects when I have the value of another property in the same object

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript if I have this value in a variable...

```
var selectedId = '2';
```

And I have this array of objects below....

```
var itemsArray = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Item 1',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Item 2',
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Item 3',
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Item 4',
    },
];
```

How can I get the `itemsArray` `name` value from the object that the value `selectedId` has.

In this example I would have the value of `2` in `selectedId` and need to get the `itemsArray[n][name]` of `Item 2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) like this

```js
var selectedId = 2;

var itemsArray = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Item 1',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Item 2',
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Item 3',
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Item 4',
    },
]; 
  
var result = itemsArray.filter(function (el) {
  return el.id === selectedId;
});
var name = result[0] && result[0].name;
console.log(name);
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you need:

```
// Give me everything in itemsArray where:
itemsArray.filter(function(item){

    // its id is the one I'm looking for,
    return (item.id === selectedId) 

// and give them to me in this form:
}).map(function(element){ 

    // just the name
    return element.name 
})
```

map() and filter(), along with reduce() and forEach(), can be extremely interesting and useful.  Especially if you're using this problem to better understand arrays or programming, I'd suggest learning how to use them all.